# Closing Selenium webdriver after X seconds

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver (firefox) on Ubuntu + Python, and run into an issue where sometimes the page doesn't load, and the whole script simply hangs.
Is there a way to force-exit the webdriver window after X seconds ?
Looking for code like the one below, that actually works though.  It looks like if the webdriver is waiting on the response, it will wait (almost) indefinitely).

```
driver.get(record)
sleep(5)
my_html = driver.page_source #get whatever we have after 5 sec
driver.close() #close driver
```

**NOTE!: The accepted answer is correct.  The issue was caused by my geckodriver being out of date (v 0.11 vs v.019).**
To check your version on ubuntu:

```
geckodriver --version   #command in terminal
```

to update the driver (if needed), [use these steps.  Note - Sandeep's answer worked best for me.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

record = "https://www.google.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
try:
    driver.get(record)
    my_html = driver.page_source #get whatever we have after 5 sec
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Setting page load timeout, as described [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout), will achieve what you're after.  It will raise a `TimeoutException` if the page doesn't load within the time given, closing the program.

Comment: thanks, any thought on why running the timeout code on ubuntu + python 2.7 would throw an error on the timeout line? getting the following message: "WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette"

Comment: this was the issue with outdated geckodriver on my machine.  oops :(

Answer (score 1):

When the page isn't loading and and the whole script simply hangs the solution would be to configure *`set_page_load_timeout()`*.

Here is an effective code block catching the *`TimeoutException`*. Irrespective of `TimeoutException` happening or not remember to call *`quit()`* method within `try-except{}` block to keep away the dangling instances of the WebDriver variants.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(2)
try :
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/the-taj-mahal-palace-tower.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYATG4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=338ad58d8e83c71e6aa78c67a2996616;dest_id=-2092174;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;hip_dst=1;hpos=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=ccd41231d2f37b82d695970f081412152a59586aX1;srpvid=c71751e539ea01ce;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl")
    print("URL successfully Accessed")
    driver.quit()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Page load Timeout Occured. Quiting !!!")
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: thanks, any thought on why running the timeout code on ubuntu + python 2.7 would throw an error on the timeout line? getting the following message: "WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette"

Comment: Message seems to be clear, `webdriver` unable to negotiate terms with `marionette`. You may require to clean up your system. If my **`Answer`** have catered to your **`Question`** please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my **`Answer`** just below the **`VoteDown`** arrow so the tick mark turns green.